# Duvida de Linux Crontab

Tags: linux, cron

Quando eu digito crontab-l eu vejo os agendamentos
Quando eu digito crontab-e eu posso editar os agendamentos

o que acontece se eu só digitar crontab ?

Sou iniciante ainda no Linux

Answer (score 0):

Segundo este [link](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) e testado no ubuntu

O comando não faz nada, no entanto, se você finalizar com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ele apaga o arquivo atual do cron, se você fechar com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ele termina e nada acontece.